# How do I add a property to MembershipUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I a using MVC4 and the default member/user tables that come with it. I added a PhoneNumber column to the Membership table.

When I get a MembershipUser with Membership.GetUser() it has a property for things like Email. I would like to make it so MembershipUsers also have a property for the PhoneNumber column that i added. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks you in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use the Profile provider for this.

If you'd rather stick with Membership for this, you're looking at creating a custom class deriving from MembershipUser, and a custom Membership provider to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom membership provider for such cases. Here is a nice tutorial around the same.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165159/Custom-Membership-Providers

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the stored procedures that membership.getuser() uses.

There is only 3:

- dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetUserByEmail
- dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetUserByName
- dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetUserByUserId

You could actually enhance these or create clones to be safer and call them directly from MVC.

Here is the most popular one:

```
USE [MVCTemplate]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_GetUserByUserId]    Script Date: 05/30/2012 22:12:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_GetUserByUserId]
    @UserId               uniqueidentifier,
    @CurrentTimeUtc       datetime,
    @UpdateLastActivity   bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
    IF ( @UpdateLastActivity = 1 )
    BEGIN
        UPDATE   dbo.aspnet_Users
        SET      LastActivityDate = @CurrentTimeUtc
        FROM     dbo.aspnet_Users
        WHERE    @UserId = UserId

        IF ( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ) -- User ID not found
            RETURN -1
    END

    SELECT  m.Email, m.PasswordQuestion, m.Comment, m.IsApproved,
            m.CreateDate, m.LastLoginDate, u.LastActivityDate,
            m.LastPasswordChangedDate, u.UserName, m.IsLockedOut,
            m.LastLockoutDate
    FROM    dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_Membership m
    WHERE   @UserId = u.UserId AND u.UserId = m.UserId

    IF ( @@ROWCOUNT = 0 ) -- User ID not found
       RETURN -1

    RETURN 0
END
GO
```